# Copying commands from ubuntu 10.04 terminal

Tags: 10.04, command-line, gnome-terminal, clipboard

Can anyone tell me the way to copy commands from the Ubuntu terminal?  I tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ins</kbd>, right click option but none of these works.

Comment: just holding single click and dragging or double click to highlight the entered command and do ctrl+shift+c , also Mouse right click copying also works.

Answer (score 3):

Just select the text you want to copy and go to the place on the screen where you'd like to paste the text. Press middle click button of mouse and its done! Its easier than the other methods...

Comment: You might want to see this page too to understand a bit more about clipboards in ubuntu. http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/xclip-linux-insert-files-command-output-intoclipboard/

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> : Copy

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> : Paste

Answer (score 1):

Use the mouse:
Right Click > Copy

Comment: On right clicking whatever i select gets deselected

Comment: Try Ctrl+Shift+C

Comment: Selecting with the mouse requires you to: Put the pointer in the Terminal, drag the pointer for the text you want using the left mouse button, *then* you right click the text and select copy.

Comment: @UriHerrera [This method](http://askubuntu.com/a/155457/22949) requires those initial steps too.

Answer (score 0):

Use the command `history` to display a list of all previously issued commands.

Next copy the commands by holding the left mouse and dragging to highlight the list, then right click and select copy.

Then open gedit, libre office or such, right click and paste, then save the file.

Comment: I used history and then after selecting everything i wanted to copy when i right clicked the things which were selected get deselected and on pressing ctrl+shift+C after selecting on terminal this comes:^C.sorry but i am new to ubuntu.